# WiX bootstrapper Project Reference Variables

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

I'm a beginner, WiX 3.7, VS2010.

Bootstrapper project.

Currently I'm blocked by:
"Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.Bootstrapper2.TargetPath)'"

Where do I find my project name?  ?Bundle name?

In the Projects tab of "Add References" there's nothing to select.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of how the project output path is going to be useful inside the bundle. Perhaps you want the path that the bundle is running from...

From the [docs](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_built_in_variables.htm):

- `WixBundleOriginalSource` — gets the source path from where the bundle was originally installed.
- `WixBundleName` — gets the name of the bundle (from Bundle/@Name). This variable can also be set by the bootstrapper application to modify the bundle name at runtime.